# creating a CSV file and then attaching to an email using boto3

Tags: python, csv, email, boto3

I have a report I created. it basically pulls data, manipulates it than sends the report to a S3 bucket. What I would like to know how to do is how I can pull that CSV from the S3 bucket and email it out. I send it to S3 for longterm retention initially.

```
other code
..
..
..
 copy_source = {'Bucket': target, 'Key': 'mycsv.csv' }
    s3client.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = target, Key = dated_file )
    s3client.delete_object(Bucket = target, Key = 'generic.csv')
```

I would like to attach the csv located in the s3 bucket to the boto3
something goes wrong.

is it possible?

lets say target = s3://mys3bucket

UPDATE:::So I have found a solution using boto3 s3_object.get_object

this will send the email and attach the attachment to the email.

```
sg = MIMEMultipart()
new_body = "The following EC2 server are up and running"
text_part = MIMEText(new_body, _subtype="html")
msg.attach(text_part)

filename='generic.csv'
msg["To"] = "randal1981@gmail.com"
msg["From"] = "randal1981@gmail.com"
s3_object = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-1')
s3_object = s3_object.get_object(Bucket=target, Key=filename)
body = s3_object['Body'].read()

part = MIMEApplication(body, filename)
part.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(part)
ses_aws_client = boto3.client('ses', 'us-west-1')
ses_aws_client.send_raw_email(RawMessage={"Data" : msg.as_bytes()})
```

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I have posted in the edit of the original question how I was able to actually send the attachment via email. what I was trying to understand is how to pull the attachment from S3. I did not explain myself very well. I found a similar solution using the boto3 call: s3_object.get_object. It worked well with my code. I hope it can help someone else...